# Metamask Mobile problem

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js

[image]

code:

```
  if (!$metamask.states.connected || !connectedAddress.value) {
      errorMessage.value = 'Please connect your wallet first.';
      showModalError.value = true;

      return;
    }

    let amountInEther = depositAmount.value;

    amountInEther = amountInEther.replace(',', '.');

    if (!amountInEther || isNaN(amountInEther) || parseFloat(amountInEther) <= 0) {
      modalState.value = true
      modalText.value = 'Please enter a valid amount greater than 0.'

      return;
    }


    const amountInWei = Web3.utils.toWei(amountInEther, 'ether');
    const referrer = referrerAddress.value;

    try {
      const transactionReceipt = await contractInfo.contract.methods.userDeposit(referrer, amountInWei).send({
        from: connectedAddress.value,
        value: amountInWei
      });
      displayDepositSuccess();
      showModalSuccess.value = true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error making the deposit:', error);
      errorMessage.value = `Error making the deposit: ${error.message || error}`;
      showModalError.value = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        showModalError.value = false;
      }, 6000);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message "`null is not an object`" suggests an issue with accessing the `contractInfo.contract.methods` object, possibly because it's not correctly initialized or defined.

I'd recommend checking the contract reference to ensure it's set up correctly before accessing its methods. This error typically occurs when the code attempts to access properties or methods of an object that doesn't exist.